# Blazor Templated components CascadingValue

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to get the context.Id (Primary Key) value in my templated component via a `[CascadingParameter]`, so I can use it in my NavigationManager. But it returns always 0.
How can i accomplish this?

Many thanks!

```
@typeparam TItem
@inject NavigationManager nav

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            <tr @onclick="@(() => nav.NavigateTo($"dossiers/{PK}/basisgegevens"))">@RowTemplate(item)</tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>@TableFooter</tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment TableFooter { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter] int PK { get; set; }

}
```

Implementation:

```
<GenericTable Items="dossiers">
    <TableHeader>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Naam</th>
        <th>Vorm</th>
        <th>Ondernemingsnummer</th>
    </TableHeader>
    <RowTemplate>
        <CascadingValue Value="@context.Id">
            <td>@context.Id</td>
            <td>@context.Name</td>
            <td>@context.LegalEntityType.Name</td>
            <td>@context.Ondernemingsnummer</td>
        </CascadingValue>
    </RowTemplate>
</GenericTable>
```

Comment: I've never done that before, but I understand the issue. TItem cannot be convert into the underlying object, but it should. I'm going to investigate this and let you know....

Comment: Of course, temporarily you can pass an array of int containing the ID values....

Comment: @enet thanks for the effort! For the passing of an int[], how do you see that?

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to go the value of the Id, using Reflection:

```
@typeparam TItem
@inject NavigationManager nav

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>@TableHeader</tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Items)
        {
            <tr @onclick="@(() => nav.NavigateTo($"dossiers/{item.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(item, null)}/basisgegevens"))">
                @RowTemplate(item)
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>@TableFooter</tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

@code {
    [Parameter] public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment TableHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<TItem> RowTemplate { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment TableFooter { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use CascadingValue to cascade values to a component that may have already been rendered. The value will always be zero. When the component is created, its parameters are set at the very beginning, before the CascadingValue component's Value parameter is assigned "@context.Id", so now it's too late.

The best solution I could come up with is to move the tr element to the RowTemplate like this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        @RowTemplate(item)
    }
</tbody>
```

And

```
<RowTemplate>
   <tr @onclick="@(() => 
            nav.NavigateTo($"dossiers/{context.Id}/basisgegevens"))">
        <td>@context.Id</td>
        <td>@context.Name</td>
        <td>@context.LegalEntityType.Name</td>
        <td>@context.Ondernemingsnummer</td>
   </tr> 
</RowTemplate>
```

This should be working. I'm afraid there is no way to cast the generic object into its underlying type. I'll do my investigation, and I'll report here my findings.